# Build error in tuc-ros package in kinect_utils

Tags: ros, kinect, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package information available here:
[Autonomous corridor flight of a UAV using the kinect sensor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Autonomous%20corridor%20flight%20of%20a%20UAV%20using%20the%20Kinect%20sensor.)

Please suggest some solution. I have attached the trace.

```
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build
  cd build && make -l4
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 14%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 28%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 50%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 50%] Built target rospack_genmsg
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 50%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  [ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/corridor_extraction.dir/src/corridor_extraction.o
  /home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/src/corridor_extraction.cpp:3:28: fatal error: libtimer/timer.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/corridor_extraction.dir/src/corridor_extraction.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/corridor_extraction.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/ros/tuc-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/tuc_pelican/kinect_utils/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package kinect_utils written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sid/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120314-215203/kinect_utils/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kinect_utils [FAIL] [ 1.27 seconds ]                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package kinect_utils. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 38 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/sid/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120314-215203
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29711/build-error-in-tuc-ros-package-in-kinect_utils/) by [Sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1971/sid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just taking a quick look at the code, it seems like you could probably switch the header to the one included in the package, that is:

Change:

```
#include <libtimer/timer.h>
```

To:

```
#include "kinect_utils/timer.h"
```

Or, you could probably remove the timer code and header, as it seems to be used for profiling purposes only.  It wouldn't be necessary to actually run the code, just determine the timing of the code.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0